# What is the correct way to completely eliminate Replication for a specific Publication

Tags: sql, replication, pull, subscriptions

I have two servers:

Server 1 (Publisher)

Server 2 (Subscriber)

I have a set up a PULL subscription.

What are the correct steps to programmatically remove this entire replication?

I need to know this because I have a custom application that does Replication and in an event of errors, I need to "start fresh" so I need to delete the publication, subscription and any other objects related to it...

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Delete the pull subscription
2. Delete the publication

Here are some links to assist you:

[Delete a Pull Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151861.aspx)

[Delete a Publication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151256.aspx)

Both examples show how to delete the pull subscription and publication using SSMS, T-SQL, and RMO.  T-SQL or RMO would be the way to go to do it programmatically.  I hope this helps.